# Python Binary Tree Implementation insert method: help required

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to create a python binary tree implementation. I believe that I have created the insert method correctly but I am having issues printing the tree using inorder traversal.

I am struggling to work out how to print each instance of the binary tree correctly. This is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
class BinaryTree():

    def __init__(self,rootid):
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.rootid = rootid

    def insert(self, item):
        if item < self.rootid:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = BinaryTree(item)
            else:
                self.left.insert(item)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = BinaryTree(item)
            else:
                self.right.insert(item)

    def inorder_print(self):
        if self.left:
            print(self.left)
        print (self.rootid)
        if self.right:
            print(self.right)


tree = BinaryTree(5)

while True:
    answer = input("Do you wish to add a value to the tree? ")
    if answer == "y":
        item = int(input("Please enter your number: "))
        tree.insert(item)
    else:
        break

tree.inorder_print()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inorder print function seems to be wrong.

For inorder print you need to recursive call `inorder_print()` for left tree, and then print the current root and then do same recursion for right tree.

Example -

```
def inorder_print(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.inorder_print()
    print (self.rootid)
    if self.right:
        self.right.inorder_print()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `inorder_print` needs to be a recursive function: it needs to descend through its children and print each one. So instead of just doing `print(self.left)`, you need to call `self.left.inorder_print()`.